# How can I solve GPU out of memory errors using LLaMA2

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, llama

I installed llama2 to run it, I'm using an RTX 3070 graphics card with 8GB VRAM,

I keep getting the following error.

`CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 86.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 7.78 GiB of which 46.88 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 7.50 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 7.32 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 1.42 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I don't know if I got it right,
I was going to allocate 86MB, I don't understand that I failed.
As shown in the executable code below, I purposely reduced all the max sizes to the minimum,
I don't know why these errors keep happening.
Is it because of a different setup error regarding the graphics card VRAM?
Or, is the original 8GB of VRAM not enough to run LLaMa2?

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_chat_completion.py \
    --ckpt_dir llama-2-7b-chat/ \
    --tokenizer_path tokenizer.model \
    --max_seq_len 1 --max_batch_size 1
```

I want to run LLaMa2 by my Graphic Cards, but It didnt run.
Below is my Graphic Card.[image]